# Add values to a key between string match instances in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary where each key is the name (of a unique DNA sequence), and its value will be a list of other names (that have the same DNA sequence). For instance `{'2617': [['5632'], ['7630'], ...}`. I'm trying to populate this dictionary from a file that has this structure:

```
  1. 11618 [82]  
11619  
11620  
12180  
  2. 12183 [1]  
  3. 12918 [2]  
12922
```

I want the key to be the 2nd item on lines that start with `\d+.`, then the values will be all the lines until the next instance of `\d+.`. I can't figure how to add these values until the next instance of the `\d+.` match.
Right now, I just have a list of the unique sequences, from:

```
unique_seqs=[]  
for line in in_file:  
    line=line.strip()  
    if '[' in line:  
        line=line.split()  
        unique_seqs.append(line[1])
```

I can make this list into dictionary values, but I don't know how to make a loop to add the keys and values at the same time from my file. Thanks in advance!  Added:
Here's a bit from the file:

```
  1. 11618 [82]
11619
11620
12180
ML_S2470
ML_S2472
  2. 12183 [1]
12922
  3. 12919 [20]
12920
12921
```

and the code that made my list in the last comment below:

```
in_file = open('example.txt', 'r')
for line in in_file:
    line=line.strip()
    line=line.split('\n')
```

Comment: Just to be clear, "11618" would be the key from the first line and its values would be the next 3 lines? And the next key, "11620", would have an empty list of values?

Comment: 11618 would be the key, and it would have the values `[[11619], [11620],[12180]]`. '11620' would not be a key, so it wouldn't have an empty list of values. In reality, '11618' would have a list of 82 values as indicated in the brackets following '11618'. I'm trying to write some code now to take advantage of the fact that I "know" how many values the key should have. Following this, the key '12183' above would not have a value.

Comment: I'm sorry, we meant the same thing, I just confused the numbers.

Comment: No worries, it's hard to explain these things when not in person!

Comment: I don't see any lines that start with `\d+.` and contain two items.

Comment: Sorry, '\d+.' is my way of saying one or two digits followed by a '.'. The '.' has to be there, or else those lines aren't distinguished from the others.

Comment: I still don't see any such lines.  The first line in your example starts with spaces, not digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.

```
with open('example.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    key = None
    sequences = {}

    for line in in_file:
        if '.' in line:
            if key:
                sequences[key] = values
            key = line.split()[1]
            values = []
        else:
            values.append([line[:-1].strip()])
    sequences[key] = values
```

Effectively, you keep a list of the values. If you find a line that has the format of a key, you store the current list of values with their respective key, empty the list and set the key to be according to the currently read line. Once you're out of lines, you simply add in the values from the last key you were working on.

Initially we have an undefined key. Since the first line will be a key, the code will enter the `if '.' in line:` block and attempt to map any values so far to our key. In order to prevent it this one time, the mapping is done inside the `if key:` block.

I used `if '.' in line` because it's guaranteed to be found earlier in the string than `'['`. However, that's a matter of preference.

It's better to open a file with the `with` syntax. But even if you do it as `in_file = open(...)`, when you iterate through the lines, they will contain a newline at the end. However, you don't need to do any premature string manipulation. First check whether the line is a key or a value. `line.split()[1]` will naturally pick out the key value for you, without having to worry about removing any whitespace or newlines. And if it is a value, `line[:-1]` will return the string without the newline, of which you can strip the whitespace.

Comment: So I can get this to work on your "dummy" example with in_file as a string, then split, but I can't get it to work with my full file. When I print your in_file, it looks like this `['  1. 11618 [82]  ', '11619  ', '11620  ', '12180  ', '  2. 12183 [1]  ', '  3. 12918 [2]  ', '12922  ']`, but when I print mine, it looks like this `['  1. 11618 [82]', '']
['11619', '']
['11620', '']`  This different structure throws off your code. I can get rid of the last item in each list by using the .strip() command, but that's not the problem. Do you have any what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is that I am generating a list for each line, `['1. 11618 [82]']\n['11619']\n['11620']`, so I have a list of lists, and yours is just a single list with each element having 1 to 3 items `[' 1. 11618 [82] ', '11619 ', '11620 ', '12180 ', ' 2. 12183 [1] ', ' 3. 12918 [2] ', '12922 ']`. I will try and add the code I am using and a snippet from the file in my original question above, I can't get this formatting down!

Comment: Okay, now I understand the result. `line.split('\n')` will return a list of the items, so if you have the string `s = 'abc\n'`, it will return `['abc', '']`. You can amend this by doing `s.split('\n')[0]`, but if you follow the suggestions from my updated questions, you will have to do minimum string manipulations. I believe this should work as intended now.

Comment: Phew, thanks so much for sticking around and helping! I'm still trying to wrap my head around 'if key' statement and having to empty the list, so I'm going to think about it some more. As for now, your code works great! I've got it looping over files now, and it seems to be working perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: In Python anything other than `None`, `False`, `0`, and an empty string/list/tuple/set/dict has a [*truthy* value](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html). So as long as `key` has a string with at least length 1, it will evaluate to `True`.